# Ruby - Find directory with specific name

Tags: ruby

Assuming I have directory structure like

```
MyDir
  + Music
  + Movies
  + Pictures
  + Videos
```

How do I find directory called Pictures using Ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dir['MyDir/Pictures']
```

Unfortunately, it this won't return you an object, you can operate with, just an array. So if you want iterate over files in this directory, you should do something like the following

```
Dir['MyDir/Pictures/*'].each do |file_name|
  # do something
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could capture the output of `Dir.pwd` and then use `ls`, like:

```
files = `ls #{Dir.pwd}`
p files # "Movies\nMusic\nPictures\nVideos\n"
p files.split.include? 'Pictures' # true
```

Or also using [Open3](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html):

```
require 'open3'

files, = Open3.capture2('ls', Dir.pwd)
p files # "Movies\nMusic\nPictures\nVideos\n"
p files.split.include? 'Pictures' # true
```

Consider you're inside the `MyDir` folder.